# Single service for multiple pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

I have 9 pods running which are basically 9 different applications.

Is it possible to have same k8s service (LB | Public IP) for multiple pods such that I can access them by different ports, but the same IP of service (LB)?

E.g. like so:
LB-IP:80 -- In the backend an application is running, which I can access.
LB-IP:8080 (Same IP as previous) -- I will run another pod in the backend.

**** Selectors will be different for each pod.**

Comment: As I understand, I would suggest you try Ingress controller which is Layer 7 Load Balancer. It makes sure that you have single public IP and more backend services

Answer (score 6):

As for the pure service approach, no it is not possible. Service relates to only one selector so you can't.

Now, as you talk about LB here, you might be talking about exposing the thing externally, and for that you can have an Ingress/IngressController. If you want, you can also just deploy a "gateway" service that will do the thing for you (ie. HA proxy configured to expose these different ports you want)

If your environment does not support ingress, you might want to deploy ie. [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) which does a great job for the point of entry to your services

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What I did was I reserved a static IP and then assigned the same IP to multiple services ( Different service.yaml files ) and changed the ports for the backend. Like one Load Balancer (service) with a static IP is pointing to a backend service and the same Load balancer with the same IP ( different service file ) is pointing to other service on different port. I monitored this for one day and everything seems to be normal.

Comment: @Saurabh how did you reserve that IP? Is it different to dinamically assigned ip? when i use dynamicaly assigned ip only one service can use 1 ip address