# Accessing Spark-Master from a containerized spark docker image from the same minikube Node

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have deployed "spark-hadoop" docker image on the docker container in minikube.

I have created kubectl services on Kubernetes for the spark components like spark-master, spark-worker and spark-ui.
I have exposed spark-master as a KubeService via NodePort and hence i can access the spark-webui page as:

`http://{minikubeIP}:{Nodeport}`

from my chrome browser inside minikube

The sparkui webpage at `http://{minikubeIP}:{Nodeport}` on the broswer displays the typical spark job dashboard and also mentioned that spark-master is alive and running at "`spark://spark-master:7077`".

Now the issue is how should i access "spark-master" URL from my another docker containerized application. In this other application i have mentioned `{spark.master=spark://spark-master:7077"}` in application.properties. When starting up the application gives error like "Master not responsive" and it shuts down.
Any pointers on this will help.

```
minispark@minispark-VirtualBox: kubectl describe svc spark-master

Name:                     spark-master
Namespace:                eniq-dev
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 component=spark-master
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.97.44.8
Port:                     webui  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 webui  32396/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.8:8080
Port:                     spark  7077/TCP
TargetPort:               7077/TCP
NodePort:                 spark  31599/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.8:7077
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Other application is also in the same kubernetes cluster? Do you have a service with name `spark-master` which exposed spark master pod? If not then try using the IP of spark master pod

Comment: @Arghya, Yes i have a service with the name of "spark-master" and it is exposed via nodeport. AS mentioned in my question I am able to access the UI port with 8080. It is the "7077: port" the main spark master that I am unable to access from my application. All the Spark and my application are in the same Node since this is minikube (with 1 node).

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe svc spark-master`.

Comment: ok done added output

Comment: If you do curl from another pod to `172.18.0.8:7077` does it work or you get connection refused? Can you check if a container is listening on port 7077?

Comment: No response it times out Error:  "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.18.0.8 port 7077: Connection timed out

Comment: Interesting do you have any network policy which blocks anything other than port 8080?. can you try curl to `10.97.44.8:7077`

Comment: No policy. I think it is the nature of spark. Please check this article. i have the same setup. With one difference. In the article the author accesses the docker container and runs the programs inside the docker image. I wanted to access this from another docker image. That being the only difference.  https://medium.com/@kienmn97/deployment-of-standalone-spark-cluster-on-kubernetes-ba15978658bf

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Comment: No I have not solved it. The way i have understood it is that the apps need to be inside the spark container for it to work and distribute it efficiently to worker nodes. Therefore all the articles on web follow this approach. They submit the job to spark (as a jar) to the spark master after logging inside the docker container.In my case, I could can see that my calls are hitting the container as per container logs. Therefore the bottom line is even if exposed and accessible we cannot submit a job to Spark master from outside. This is my understanding not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As for the pure service approach, no it is not possible. Service relates to only one selector so you can't assign another application in different pod to the same service.

If you are running two containers in the same pod use different ports inside the pod or use separate pods. Create deployment if there is no shared resources like filesystem - it would be easy to split the containers to separate pods.

**Note** that it will not suffice to change the pod definition if you want to have both containers running in the same pod with different ports. The application in the container must bind to a different port as well.

However best solution is to create another service which will point to different application and access it via different url.

Take a look: [single-service-for-multiple-pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223585/single-service-for-multiple-pods), [how-to-configure-multiple-services-containers-in-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751220/how-to-configure-multiple-services-containers-in-kubernetes), [multi-container-pods-communication](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/), [understanding-multi-container-pods](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/understanding-multi-container-pods-12f5780f3956).

Comment: Iam not sure i understand this is a simple matter of Service A (my application plannig to use Spark) deployed in one pod backed by docker image. calling Service b(Spark Master) again deployed by its own docker images which is deployed in a different pod. Whtever you have mentioned in the best solution is what i have been trying to do. This issue is more Spark related than K8.